# Opendsitro JDBC index table import from h2o

Tags: elasticsearch, h2o, elasticsearch-opendistro

I am trying to import elasticsearch index table in a third party application(h2o) as sql table using opendistro jdbc driver by giving below connection url but only index columns(schema) are imported.Data(records) is not imported.

```
    conn_url = “jdbc:elasticsearch://https://127.0.0.1:9200?trustSelfSigned=true”
    table = “testindex”
    username = “admin”
    password = “admin”
    
    Can you Please advice this above connection url is correct or not.In opendistro sql jdbc documentation there are many property key values are mentioned in connection url.Am i missing anything here.
    [![enter image description here][1]][1]
    jdbc:elasticsearch://[scheme://][host][:port][/context-path]?[property-key=value]&[property-key2
    =value2]…&[property-keyN=valueN]
    
    I am attaching screenshots of table import .Please suggest.
```

[image]

Comment: @Opendistro team..Please suggest

Comment: Hey @Sarvendra, have you solved this issue ? I Think you will have an issue with your connection URL